# SQL basic issue

Tags: sql

```
   select x_pick.prod_code, x_order.order_state, x_pick.pick_state, x_pick.pick_qty, x_pick.pick_location, x_order.wave_id, x_prod.normal_pick_area, x_apr_loc.location, x_order.reqd_despatch_time, x_prod.bncd_awkward_item, sub1.LOC_COUNT
from x_pick, x_order, x_prod, x_apr_loc,

(select X_PICK.prod_CODE, COUNT(DISTINCT( X_APR_LOC.LOCATION)) AS LOC_COUNT
from X_APR_LOC, X_PICK
where X_APR_LOC.prod_CODE (+) = X_PICK.prod_CODE
group by X_PICK.prod_code) sub1,

(select x_prod.normal_pick_area,x_pick.pick_location,
(case when  x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'TP' then 'Miniload'
when x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'MTP' then 'Miniload'
when x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'PL' then 'Pallet Live'
when x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'HLOP' then 'HLOP'
when x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'STILLAGE' then 'High Value'
when x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'ZA' then 'Aerosol'
when x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'ZH' then 'Haz Shed'
when x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'APR' and substr(x_pick.pick_location,3,2) < 22 and x_prod.bncd_awkward_item = 'YES'  then 'APR Awkward'
when x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'APR' and substr(x_pick.pick_location,3,2) < 22 and x_prod.bncd_awkward_item = 'NO'  then 'APR'
when x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'APR' and substr(x_pick.pick_location,3,2) > 21 and x_prod.bncd_awkward_item = 'NO'  then 'APR 2'
when x_prod.normal_pick_area = 'APR' and substr(x_pick.pick_location,3,2) > 21 and x_prod.bncd_awkward_item = 'YES'  then 'TD1'
else 'Unknown' end) from x_pick) area,


where x_pick.prod_code  (+) = sub1.prod_code
and x_pick.prod_code = x_apr_loc.prod_code (+)
and x_pick.prod_code = x_prod.prod_code
and x_pick.order_id = x_order.order_id
and x_pick.pick_state in('RESERVED','WAIT REPLEN','STARTED')
and x_order.order_state in('RESERVED','STARTED')
```

Part of a larger query. Initially I am getting an invalid parathensis message, I can get rid of this but am them getting invalid identifier error message, even though all the fields I'm using have been called. I am pretty new to SQL so any help would be great!.

Comment: Sorry may have had slight issues with formatting.

Comment: you miss a comma after pick_location (its first occurence)

Comment: Still getting invalid table name even though the tables are valid

Comment: Which invalid table name? do x_item and x_ploc both exist? Are they in the default schema?

Comment: You want us to find a problem with your query, but only giving us a part of the whole query. How do you expect us to know which tables are present?

Comment: Some tips:1)avoid from x_pick, x_order, x_prod, x_apr_loc,... and use JOIN clause; 2) when you have a problem like this, cut off part till it works and then add again them one by one; 3) simplify your query as you can; 4) adopt a "standard" fow writing (use indent, etc.)

Comment: Please do not deface your question, once posted it belongs to SO (and people have taken time to post answers), if you like to remove your name from it use the SE contact us link

Comment: Sorry, I will readd it shortly.

Comment: Why did you just remove the SQL from your question (again)? Without it your question has no context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below there was two issue First need to add comma after pick_location second from x_item will be after column name, Hopefully it will work at your side as well

```
(select x_item.pick_area,x_item.awkward_item,x_ploc.pick_location,
(case when  x_prod.normal_pick_area = '0' then 'Z'
when x_item.pick_area = '1' then 'A'
when x_item.pick_area = '2' then 'B'
when x_item.pick_area = '3' then 'C'
when x_item.pick_area = '4' then 'D'
when x_item.pick_area = '5' then 'E'
when x_item.pick_area = '6' then 'F'
when x_item.pick_area = '7' and substr(x_ploc.pick_location,3,2) < 22 and
                                    x_prod.awkward_item = 'YES'  then 'G'
when x_item.normal_pick_area = 'APR' and substr(x_ploc.pick_location,3,2)
   < 22 and x_item.awkward_item = 'NO'  then 'H'

when x_item.pick_area = 'APR' and substr(x_ploc.pick_location,3,2) > 21  
 and x_item.awkward_item = 'NO'  then 'I'
when x_item.pick_area = 'APR' and substr(x_ploc.pick_location,3,2) > 21   
and x_item.awkward_item = 'YES'  then 'J'

else 'Unknown' end)  area from x_item)
```

Comment: Do I not need to call from x_item, x_ploc at the end? Seems to run when i do that. (It doesnt match the main code now as thats been updated to a current version, easy to swap between the two though)

Comment: you don't need to pass table name within case statement, after case statement and column list you can pu table name like below,    Select <Column-Name1>,<Column-NameN>, <Casestatement1>,<CasestatementN> from <Table_Name>    Hope this will help

Comment: SELECT column list, function(), function(), ...

            FROM table1

                INNER JOIN table2

                ...

                ON table1.col1 = table2.col2

                ...

            WHERE criteria for row selection

            [AND criteria for row selection]
            [OR criteria for row selection]

           
  GROUP BY column list

            HAVING criteria for function results

          
            ORDER BY column list

Comment: Ye i understand that :) was just saying the SQL would execute until the last line was

else 'Unknown' end)  area from x_item,x_item)

Comment: Yes the SQL would execute until the last line was else 'Unknown' end) area from x_item,x_item)

Comment: I meant wouldn't if thatwas confusing! I need both tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
(select x_item.pick_area,x_item.awkward_item,x_ploc.pick_location,
case when  x_prod.normal_pick_area = '0' then 'Z'
when x_item.pick_area = '1' then 'A'
when x_item.pick_area = '2' then 'B'
when x_item.pick_area = '3' then 'C'
when x_item.pick_area = '4' then 'D'
when x_item.pick_area = '5' then 'E'
when x_item.pick_area = '6' then 'F'
when x_item.pick_area = '7' and substr(x_ploc.pick_location,3,2) < 22 and                                
x_prod.awkward_item = 'YES'  then 'G'
when x_item.normal_pick_area = 'APR' and substr(x_ploc.pick_location,3,2)     
< 22 and x_item.awkward_item = 'NO'  then 'H'
when x_item.pick_area = 'APR' and substr(x_ploc.pick_location,3,2) > 21     
and x_item.awkward_item = 'NO'  then 'I'
when x_item.pick_area = 'APR' and substr(x_ploc.pick_location,3,2) > 21     
and x_item.awkward_item = 'YES'  then 'J'
else 'Unknown' end from x_item
```

This should fix it.